# Is this ODE system well known?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I was trying to construct ODE system with solution stays in constrained area and end up with this:
$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = -\cos\left(\frac{y}{z+1}\right)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} = -\sin\left(\frac{x}{z+1}\right)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt} = \cos(x) - \sin(z) $$
With initial conditions $$x_0=0.14\,,\; y_0=3.52\,,\; z_0=1.35$$ it looks like this with $t$ in range $[0,100000]$ and step $0.1$ by $8$ order RK solver (scipy library solve_ivp):

[image]

Visualization of phase space $x,y,z-t$ annotated by color, blue at start $[0]$ and red at end $[100000]$.

I wonder if there is something specific about this system? Does solution always stays at some radius about empty region with $\,t\to\infty\,?$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nice attractor. Are you sure $\dot z$ is correct?

Comment: @MariusS.L. yes, there is the python code of it (I reduced max time):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def attractor(t, f):
    x,y,z = f
    return -np.cos(y/(z+1)), -np.sin(x/(z+1)), np.cos(x) - np.sin(z)

sol_attractor = solve_ivp(attractor, [0, 10000], [0.14, 3.52, 1.35], dense_output=True, max_step=0.1, method='DOP853')
```
Not providing plotting code because it dooes not fit in comment max characters restriction

Edited: sorry, I cannot handle Python tabs correctly there, but everything are pretty much one-liners